# Short-cut when adding items to a list

Tags: vb.net, list

In some languages there are short-cuts when adding items into collections.

I have the following:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim letters As List(Of String)
    letters = New List(Of String)

    letters.Add("a")
    letters.Add("1")
    letters.Add("2")
    letters.Add("3")
    letters.Add("x")
    letters.Add("d")

End Sub
```

Is there a short hand way of executing this. The following does not work but maybe there's some similar syntax in `VB.NET`:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim letters As List(Of String)
    letters = New List(Of String){"a","1","2","3","x","d"}

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS2010 you should be able to do this in VB.NET:

```
 Dim letters As List(Of String)
 letters = New List(Of String) From {"a","1","2","3","x","d"}
```

The `From` can be swapped for brackets:

```
 letters = New List(Of String) ({"a","1","2","3","x","d"})
```

Nice related article: [**MSDN HERE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx)

Comment: +1 seems to work fine - although I'd have thought it would be more in connection with the version of the Framework that I'm using?

Comment: I'm using C# mainly, VB.NET only if someone points a gun to my head. So i never bother to remember which compiler version supports which feature for VB.NET.

Comment: I have a couple of small `C#` apps in production but the course I'm currently studying is `VB.NET`. Both languages use the same framework so I'm hoping I learn lots from the VB course that can be applied to `C#`.

Comment: About 90% of VB and C# code is almost identical code if you remove the semicolon.  The issue is usually how they each do conversions and such.  As a VB.Net user I read a lot of C# code, since that is what people mostly code in on MSDN and other sites. Learning to read others code will probably help you the most. Enjoy.

Comment: I've just come across this line of code `letters.Add("6"c)` what does the `c` mean ....is it a short-cut for the conversion method `ToString`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string array (input() in my example).  Another option is pass the list of strings to the constructor or use [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
    Dim input() As String = { "A", _
                              "B", _
                              "C" }

    Dim listA As New List(Of String)(input)

    dim listB as New List(Of String)
    listB.AddRange(input)
```

HTH Wade